# Unable to change tclsh path

Tags: linux, bash, tcl

I want to change my tclsh from /import/vne/bin/tclsh to /import/desapps/tcl/bin/tclsh. I am doing

```
export PATH=$PATH:/import/desapps/tcl/bin/tclsh
```

But, still if I open a tclsh and do 'which tclsh' its showing /import/vne/bin/tclsh and not the new one. Not sure where I am going wrong.

I have tried this too which also failed to work:

```
export PATH=/import/desapps/tcl/bin/tclsh:$PATH
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
export PATH=/import/desapps/tcl/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: I should have mentioned in the question that I have tried it too, it did not work

Comment: Did you try removing the 'tclsh' from the path. Just specify the directory?

Comment: Removed the tclsh. This works: export PATH=/import/desapps/tcl/bin:$PATH. Thank you.

Comment: Copy-paste works :) If you had copy-pasted my answer above :)